# Matplotlib Legend showing wrong legend name

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Using matlplotlib in Jupyter notebook .
Here's the code :

```
tesla['Open'].plot(title='Open Prices',figsize=(16,6),legend='Tesla')
gm['Open'].plot(legend='GM')
ford['Open'].plot(legend='Ford')
plt.legend()
```

Output :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozseA.png

The Desired result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvsJ.png

Comment: `legend` can be True or False. Probably you meant to use `label` instead.

Comment: Yeah ... wow i really did not see that , i meant label but instead typed legend .. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you must replace the keyword `legend` with `label`:

```
tesla['Open'].plot(title='Open Prices',figsize=(16,6),label='Tesla')
gm['Open'].plot(label='GM')
ford['Open'].plot(label='Ford')
plt.legend()
```